# Unable to save image in file path - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Below is how i save image path into my database. Now when i save the product and the image, the path is saved as `uploads/catalog/images/3423423423.jpg`  in my database.  But the issue is, i cannot find the image in the folder `uploads/catalog/images`.

What am i not doing right please?

```
public function upload(Request $request, $id)
{

        try {
            $product = Product::findorfail($id);

            if ( $request->hasFile('image'))
            {
               $path =  $request->file('image')->store('uploads/catalog/images');

               $file_name = $request->file('image')->hashName();

               $product->saveProduct($request);

               $product->images()->create(['path' => $file_name]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Exception('Try again: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form  id="product-save-form"
          action="{{route('user.product.update', $model->id)}}"
          enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">

    <div  class="row" id="product-save-accordion" data-children=".product-card">
        <div class="col-12 mb-2 mt-2">
            <div class="card product-card  mb-2 mt-2">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#product-save-accordion"
                   class="float-right" href="#basic">
                <!-- <div class="card-header">
                    Basic Details
                </div> -->
                </a>
                <div class="card-body collapse show" id="basic">
                    @include('mage2-ecommerce::admin.product.card.basic', ['editMethod' => true])
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="jQuery('#product-save-form').submit()">
        Edit Product
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="location='{{ route('user.product.index') }}'">
        Cancel
    </button>
</div>
    </form>
```

Comment: check if you have write permission on that folder

Comment: Can you post the form html too.

Comment: @claudio, how do i check that please?

Comment: @Option please check my update

Comment: I've posted a generic answer which has been tested and works my end. Again mentioned in my answer, I can't quite figure what the $id is being used for..

Comment: You need to use `$request()->image->move(public_path('uploads/catalog/images'), $filename);`

Comment: You need to also give the permission to `public` folder to save an images! Like: `sudo chmod 777 public`

Comment: @HirenGohel, there's another folder in public called `users` and with that folder, i am able to get the images saved there. so i am quite sure public already has the permission

Comment: Then check for `uploads/catalog/images` and try to give permissions to that folder

Comment: @HirenGohel thank you very much. my code is actually okay  but then i didn't have permission.. Thanks a lot

Comment: Ok, Glad i could help you! Let me post my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is fine and it seems working OK. You just need to give the permission to save that all images to that folder! (i.e. `uploads/catalog/images` folder)

Try to give the permission to `uploads/catalog/images` like:

```
sudo chmod 777 public/uploads/catalog/images
```

Hope this fixed your issue!

Answer (score 2):

I can't quite figure out why you're passing findOrFail($id) in as it's not storing into the database under an id, therefore, I haven't included it in my function/queries...

Here's the generic layout for image storing / moving:

```
  public function upload(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
        if($files=$request->file('image')){
            $path = public_path('uploads/catalog/images');

            $name= $files->getClientOriginalName();

            $files->move($path, $name);

            $product->create([
                'image' => $name
            ]);
        }
    }
```